# CSS Grid repeat with different values on different rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to create a layout within the same grid, using the:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px))
```

Now on the first row I need 2 bigger elements that are min-width 400px, but I want to do it using the same grid, and obviously, they need to go to a new line when no longer fitting the container, is this possible? Or should I just try and manipulate the incoming data and create 2 separate grids?

to simplify:

```
| x | x |
|x|x|x|x|
|x|x|x|x|
```

And I like to achieve this without the use of media queries,

```
grid-column: span 2
```

does not fully work because if the 3rd item fits, it is displayed next to the 2nd e.g.:

```
|   x   |
|  x  |x|
| x | x |
```

Anyone with any ideas?

You can see my current layout [here](https://codepen.io/marius-slovikas/pen/QWpdvzK)

Comment: Do you have to use grid-template-columns or just grid in general?  Because what you're describing is the perfect use case for grid-template-areas.

Comment: Think of it as you receive product data and you do not know how many products will be displayed, on 1 page there might be 12 on the other 3, so I don't think grid areas are well adjusted for dynamic data

Comment: to me it seems better suited for flexbox with flex-wrap and flex-grow combinated.

Comment: This is possible with grid, You can't have different number of columns per row, Probably doable with flexbox But why not simply split the first two elements into their own container ?

Comment: Splitting the first 2 elements to a separate container would require back-end intervention with a break in a for loop and continuing later. I think the best solution will be to keep the same layout for all items. I tried flexbox, with the first 2 elements having bigger widths but still on screen breaks, the second row contains 2 elements and requires media query intervention.